# Registering Spring Batch application in Spring Cloud data flow in Linux

Tags: linux, spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have deployed my spring batch application to a Linux environment and my SCDF local server also, now I want to register my spring batch application to SCDF. In windows, i did it by giving the jar file path. eg: file:///filePath/fineName. In Linux i could get the file path as /user/filePath/fileName. Now I need to register that file path to SCDF. Please suggest me how we can do that in Linux environment.

Comment: There might be some mis-understandings here.   Spring Cloud Data Flow uses Spring Boot modules not Spring Batch.   I would not say it is absolutely impossible to merge but I do not see anyone discussing it anywhere.   I do not believe this is not an intended or supported use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application registration process for Spring Cloud Data Flow is the same regardless of if you're on a Windows machine or a Linux machine.  Both cases support a file path to the executable Spring Boot application.  You can read more about registering your applications in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-stream-apps